# Why does Class.getPermittedSubclasses() return Class<?>[] and not Class<? extends T>[]

Tags: java, class, generics, constructor, java-sealed-type

I have a sealed interface that permits 3 types.

```
sealed interface Parent permits ChildA, ChildB, ChildC {}

record ChildA(long num) implements Parent {}
record ChildB(long num) implements Parent {}
record ChildC(long num) implements Parent {}
```

I want to get the constructor of each type, so I tried the following.

```
Parent.class.getPermittedSubclasses();
```

However, the return type of `getPermittedSubclasses()` is `Class<?>`. Why would it not be `Class<? extends Parent>`? Sealed interfaces are a brand new feature that do not have any dependencies. So why artificially restrict the return type in a way that makes the method less usable?

If the method returned `Class<? extends Parent>`, I could turn around and do the following.

```
Class<? extends Parent> clazz = Parent.class.getPermittedSubclasses();
Class<Long> constructorParameter = Long.class;
Constructor<? extends Parent> constructor = clazz.getConstructor(constructorParameter);
Parent p = constructor.newInstance();
```

Now to be clear, I can get past this by doing `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`, and then just forcefully casting the value to be exactly what I want, but obviously, that is not ideal at all.

As is, this is just arbitrarily limiting for no benefit that I can see. So can someone explain why this is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this were apparently type safety concerns regarding generic arrays, see [JDK-8246278](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8246278) and the referenced [mailing list post](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/amber-spec-experts/2020-October/002625.html).

Though arguably that decision is rather questionable because it sacrifices usability for a rather contrived corner case (which most likely will never occur in regular code).
Additionally there are other existing methods such as [`Class.getTypeParameters()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getTypeParameters()) with return type `TypeVariable<Class<T>>[]` which suffer from the same (contrived) issue (there also exists the "Won't Fix" issue [JDK-5063716](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-5063716) for this).

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for your response! Understanding their justification for it now, I can see why they did what they did (to follow preexisting convention). Definitely agree though, this still feels out of place.